# Dynamicly select object using number from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering, if it's possible to do something like :

I have new object:

```
// Create new object form existing code
var v1 = $("#div1").getMyObject();
```

Now i can use v1 object, for example:

```
v1.start();
```

Now question is:
i have some variable, for example:
var num = 1;

Now i want to find a way to select v1 object, using num variable (this of course will not work, but i want to show, what i need):

```
v+num.start()
```

So you see, i want to use var num, and assign this var to object name, for later use.

I'm asking, because, i need to select proper object in loop, and want to select this dynamicly.

Thank you for advice.

Comment: Use an array or object instead of seperate variables, and it's trivial to iterate over them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having objects like:

```
v1, v2, ....
```

You should have:

```
v[1], v[1], ....
```

Then you can use

```
v[1] = $("#div1").getMyObject();
v[num].start();
```